# How can I create a scrollable list that takes all available space?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a scrollable list that automatically expands taking the available space.

Here is my actual code which is working but specifying a fixed height of 610:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> _myTable;

  const MyWidget(this._myTable);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Stackoverflow example'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: const Color.fromRGBO(33, 33, 33, 0.2),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 610,
                color: const Color.fromRGBO(33, 33, 33, 0.2),
                child: _myTable.isEmpty
                    ? const Center(
                        child: Text('Loading table...'),
                      )
                    : ListView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                          return Text(_myTable[index]);
                        },
                        itemCount: _myTable.length,
                      ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If I remove that `height: 610,` line I will get the following error:

```
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderViewport#827e1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
RenderObject: RenderViewport#827e1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    needs compositing
    parentData: <none> (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
    size: MISSING
    axisDirection: down
    crossAxisDirection: right
    offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#2ab34(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#6a07b, ScrollDirection.idle)
    anchor: 0.0
    center child: RenderSliverPadding#4985e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
        constraints: MISSING
        geometry: null
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero
        textDirection: ltr
        child: RenderSliverList#33a39 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
            parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
            constraints: MISSING
            geometry: null
            no children current live
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#827e1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2009 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
```

And that error is pointing to this line of my code:

```
: ListView.builder(
```

My idea is that if I create a list with a fixed height of 610 if I move it to another device it will crash or look bad... so how can I make the scrollable list to take all available height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about using the CustomScrollView which can help you solve your problem, see the code below

`main.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return const MaterialApp(
            title: "My App",
            home: HomePage(),
        );
    }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  const HomePage({super.key});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            title: const Text("My super App")
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              child: Text("Header view"),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            List.generate(20, (idx) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.check_circle),
                      title: Text("Item $idx"),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              })
                ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```